# SonarQube to have a Quality Profile for Python PEP8 standard

Tags: python, sonarqube

How can we create a Quality Profile for Python that follows PEP8 standard?

I have enabled `Python-PEP8` under Quality Profiles for Python. I have installed Python plugin `sonar-python-plugin-1.14.1.3143.jar`.

[image]